# Sync with the multiple delegates and calling the function to update

Tags: ios, objective-c

Assume below are the callbacks/Delegate methods

```
- (void)updatedAppleLists{}

- (void)updatedOrangeLists{}
```

**The above functions can be called with no order, Need to call the below func when above two called**

```
- (void)whenBothMethodsFinished{}
```

---

Below is the simplest way to achieve :

```
BOOL isUpdatedOrrages = false;
BOOL isUpdatedApples = false;
- (void)updatedAppleLists
{
    isUpdatedApples = true;
    [self whenBothMethodsFinished];
}

- (void)updatedOrangeLists
{
    isUpdatedOrrages = true;
    [self whenBothMethodsFinished];

}

- (void)whenBothMethodsFinished
{
    if (isUpdatedOrrages & isUpdatedApples)
    {
        NSLog(@"");
        NSLog(@"Both are updated");
    }
}
```

**Here can we have a better approach without using the bool instances.?**

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, just written code to understand, updated the code